# What does the sailing ship seen at the end of Maïna symbolise?

Tags: ending, maina

At the end of *Maïna*, just before the credits roll, a ship with a sail is seen by the main character. What kind of ship is it? Who is sailing the ship? What does the sailed ship mean to the main character's story?

[image]

Comment: I'm guessing that it represents the arrival of Europeans in the area, generally a bad thing for any indigenous people who happen to be in the vicinity; http://quatr.us/northamerica/after1500/history/inuit.htm